# Unexpected behaviour of QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to create a GUI using pyqt5 that switches back and forth between two windows, namely WindowA and WindowB. In order to achieve that, I have

- Created a class for WindowA and another class for WindowB, with a button in each one
- Created a mainWindow class, which instantiates an object of type WindowA and another one of type WindowB, and added both objets to a stack. According to the [pyqt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html),

> "The QStackedWidget class provides a stack of widgets where only one widget is visible at a time."

- Defined two methods inside the mainWindow class, LaunchA and LaunchB, which set the current widget to A or B respectively using the setCurrentWidget() method and call the other one when the button is clicked.

The first couple times it works just fine. I click button A, it brings be to window B. I click button B, it brings me back to window A. However after that it starts registering multiple clicks, as if I clicked the current button and all the previously shown ones at once. I do not know how to fix this. Here is a (minimal?) reproducible example that showcases the problem. I also implemented a function that counts how many times the buttons were pressed, so that you can see the difference between the expected result and the actual result.

```
import sys 
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.Qt import QAction, QMenu


class WindowA(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WindowA, self).__init__(parent)
        self.buttonA = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button A - Press me!")
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonA)
        self.buttonA.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        layout.setSpacing(1)
        self.setLayout(layout)
    def whenButtonPressed(self, count):
        print("Button A pressed. Total buttons pressed: " + str(count))

class WindowB(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WindowB, self).__init__(parent)
        self.buttonB = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button B - Press me!")
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonB)
        self.buttonB.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        layout.setSpacing(1)
        self.setLayout(layout)
    def whenButtonPressed(self, count):
        print("Button B pressed. Total buttons pressed: " + str(count))

class mainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(mainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(850, 250, 300, 150)
        self.count = 0
        # Instantiating the classes of each window and adding them to the stack
        self.__A = WindowA()
        self.__B = WindowB()
        self.__stack = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self)
        self.__stack.addWidget(self.__A)
        self.__stack.addWidget(self.__B)
        self.__stack.setContentsMargins(1,1,1,1)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.__stack)
        self.launchA()
    def launchA(self):
        self.__stack.setCurrentWidget(self.__A)
        self.__stack.currentWidget().buttonA.clicked.connect(lambda: self.printAndChange())
        self.show()
    def launchB(self):
        self.__stack.setCurrentWidget(self.__B)
        self.__stack.currentWidget().buttonB.clicked.connect(lambda: self.printAndChange())
        self.show()
    def printAndChange(self):
        self.count += 1
        self.__stack.currentWidget().whenButtonPressed(self.count)
        if isinstance(self.__stack.currentWidget(), WindowA) == True : 
            self.launchB()
        elif isinstance(self.__stack.currentWidget(), WindowA) == False:
            self.launchA()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    w = mainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 10, if that matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are in the wrong place linking the object-signal-slot. Try it:

```
import sys 
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.Qt import QAction, QMenu


class WindowA(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WindowA, self).__init__(parent)
        self.buttonA = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button A - Press me!")
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonA)
        self.buttonA.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        layout.setSpacing(1)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        
    def whenButtonPressed(self, count):
        print("Button A pressed. Total buttons pressed: " + str(count))


class WindowB(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WindowB, self).__init__(parent)
        self.buttonB = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button B - Press me!")
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonB)
        self.buttonB.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        layout.setSpacing(1)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        
    def whenButtonPressed(self, count):
        print("Button B pressed. Total buttons pressed: " + str(count))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.setGeometry(850, 250, 300, 150)
        self.count = 0
        # Instantiating the classes of each window and adding them to the stack
        self.__A = WindowA()
        self.__A.buttonA.clicked.connect(lambda: self.printAndChange())       # +++
                
        self.__B = WindowB()
        self.__B.buttonB.clicked.connect(lambda: self.printAndChange())       # +++
        
        self.__stack = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self)
        self.__stack.addWidget(self.__A)
        self.__stack.addWidget(self.__B)
        self.__stack.setContentsMargins(1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.__stack)
        self.launchA()
        
    def launchA(self):
        self.__stack.setCurrentWidget(self.__A)
#        self.__stack.currentWidget().buttonA.clicked.connect(lambda: self.printAndChange())
        self.show()
        
    def launchB(self):
        self.__stack.setCurrentWidget(self.__B)
#        self.__stack.currentWidget().buttonB.clicked.connect(lambda: self.printAndChange())
        self.show()
        
    def printAndChange(self):
        self.count += 1
        self.__stack.currentWidget().whenButtonPressed(self.count)
        if isinstance(self.__stack.currentWidget(), WindowA) == True : 
            self.launchB()
        elif isinstance(self.__stack.currentWidget(), WindowA) == False:
            self.launchA()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks! that works! So I'm guessing that every time I call the method, another action is linked to the signal? I thought it would overwrite the previous one or something